# Median of a math sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, median

I have this math sequence that produces list of values:

```
(n-1)*1 , (n-2)*2 , (n-3)*3 , ... , (1)*(n-1)
```

So for `n = 5` it would produce this list of values:

1,1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3, 4

Median of this list is 2, right?
So how to calculate median for whatever n from natural numbers?

I am searching for some formula. I have already found out that number of those values is:

```
((n^2) - n) / 2
```

Comment: By the "sum" of those values, I think you mean the *number* of values.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right, I will edit that.

Comment: Ross: I think the OP is writing “$(n-i)*i$” to mean “$n-i$ $i$’s.

Comment: @SteveKass although this convention seems to have been commuted at the second $(n - 1) \ast 1$ `:)`

Comment: I am really sorry. I meant (1)*(n-1) at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count $k=\frac 14(n^2-n)$ positions  from one end of the list.  It is easier to count back from the end because the end of each group of the same number comes at the triangular numbers:  $1,3,6,10\ldots$.  Given $k$ the triangular number above it is $\lceil \frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+8k})\rceil$ so the median will be $n-\lceil \frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+2(n^2-n)})\rceil$

The place this fails is when $n+1$ is such that $\frac 12n(n-1)$, which is a triangular number, is also twice a triangular number.  One example is $n=21$ where you series has $\frac 12n(n-1)=210$ terms.  The first $105$ terms (which is $\frac 12 \cdot 14 \cdot 15$) go from $20$ through the last $7$ so many would say the median is $6.5$.  You can detect this because the square root comes out integral.  In those cases you should subtract $\frac 12$

Comment: I am sorry that I defined the sequence wrong, I edited it. Anyway, this doesn't result in median being 2 for n = 5. For 5 it is 2.2984378812835757.

Comment: It does work.  The ceiling brackets say to go up to the next whole number.  The square root is between $6$ and $7$, we subtract $1$ then divide by $2$ to get a number between $2$ and $3$, round up to $3$, and subtract from $5$ to get $2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought they were normal brackets. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer on how you come up with the values 1/2, -1, 1, and 2? I get those triangular numbers and the ceiling thing but the rest is unclear.

Comment: The solution to find the index of a triangular number is just using the quadratic formula.  You have $T_n=\frac 12n(n+1)$ which becomes $n=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+8T_n})$.  We need $n$ positive so take the plus sign in the formula.  The rest is computation.  When you got $2.3$ you should round up to $3$.